# How to return jsonp in cherrypy?

Tags: cherrypy

How to return jsonp with cherrypy? I am currently using the following to return json:

```
class Root(object):
   @cherrypy.expose
   @tools.json_out
   def index(self):
      return {'key':'value'}
```

Is there some annotation for jsonp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this implementation...

[jsonp](http://snipplr.com/view/15486/)

Hope this helps,

Andrew

Comment: That example appears to just return 'Works' how does it actually return jsonp?

Comment: the tag: @jsonp runs the jsonp handler.  Then Jquery handles the jsonp: $.ajax({url:"localhost:8080/", data:{'key':'value'}, dataType:"jsonp", success:onMyMethodComplete});

Comment: oh - this link has great jsonp info... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about